# Possible to determine classes to import at runtime / Possible to ignore import errors?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, class, import

**QUESTION 1**

I'm *99% sure* that you can't determine which other classes a class imports at runtime...but just in case...is this something you can do?

**QUESTION 2**

Is it possible to have your app ignore an import error? I.e., is there a way to make your app still compile and run even if you include `#import "IrrelevantClass.h"` and don't include `IrrelevantClass.h/.m` in your Xcode project?

**(WHAT I'M GETTING AT...)**

I've created a custom class `RulesManager.h/.m` with some generic methods for taking appropriate actions based on a given rules class `RulesManager_<ProjectName>.h/.m` where each Xcode project has its own rules class. (Let's use Xcode project `MyProject` as an example, so our two files will be `RulesManager.h/.m` and `RulesManager_MyProject.h/.m`.)

Currently, `RulesManager_MyProject.h` imports `RulesManager.h`, and all of my classes in my project import `RulesManager_MyProject.h` so that my classes can call something like `[RulesManager shouldExecuteGivenParameters:parameters rulesClass:rulesClass]` and take appropriate actions given both the provided parameters and the static rules outlined within the rules class, in this case `RulesManager_MyProject.m`. (Hope that wasn't too confusing...)

However, instead of importing `RulesManager_MyProject.h` in all of my project files, I'd like to import `RulesManager.h` in all of my project's classes and obtain the rules file via something like `NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"RulesManager_%@", [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject]])`. However, this doesn't work because you need to remember to import the file explicitly via `#import "RulesManager_MyProject.h"` prior to compiling. An "alternative" idea would be just to import all relevant `RulesManager_<ProjectName>.h` files in each class, but then you get the issue in Question 2 above.

The reason I'm looking to do something like this is so that I can re-use the `RulesManager.h/.m` class in all of my Xcode projects (without copying) and re-use my classes that use the rules manager (again, without copying) and instead simplify my method call to something like `[RulesManager shouldExecuteGivenParameters:parameters]` and have `rulesClass` be implicit based on the current Xcode project.

What is nice about this implementation is that I have unique central file (`RulesManager_<ProjectName>.h/.m`) in every Xcode project where I can specify unique project-wide rules (e.g., for debugging) while also having a class shared across projects (`RulesManager.h/.m`) for implementing the logic behind those rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Strictly speaking, this doesn't even make sense, a class doesn't import anything. A file can import other files, but (in objective-c) those files can have arbitrary content, multiple classes, only part of a class, etc. Regardless, you can't tell at runtime what came from where (except possibly reading your own binary and inspecting the debug symbols? Even then I don't think you can tell what imported what).

Q2. No, an error is an error because the compiler (actually preprocessor here) can't recover from it. Otherwise you get warnings (unless you use `-Werror` or a couple other clang options).

> I'd like to import RulesManager.h in all of my project's classes and obtain the rules file via something like `NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"RulesManager_%@", [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject]])`. However, this doesn't work because you need to remember to import the file explicitly via `#import "RulesManager_MyProject.h"` prior to compiling.

Have you tried it? In Objective-C, classes are resolved at runtime so you can use a class the compiler doesn't know about. It's bad for type and name-safety, but you can do it. An `import` only tells the compiler it should process the specified file, which will usually (in objc) contain an `@interface` that tells the compiler what it needs for typechecking and name safety.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that you could still call a class without explicitly "importing" it via `#import`. At some point I'd love to / I'll have to *actually* read up on how Obj-C works instead of just using it.